# Average search complexity in a randomly populated QuadTree

Tags: complexity-theory, quadtree

I have a Quad Tree filled with N random 2D points (x,y).

I what to estimate what would be the average search complexity in these two cases

1) range search (within distance R from a position x,y)

2) a single nearest point (x,y)

My reasoning so far is as follows - If we make analogy with the Binary Tree average complexity - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Which is

[image: log_{2}N]

For a single search the average complexity for a QuadTree should be something like (because there are 4 childs):

[image: O(log_{4}N) + 4O(k)]

Where k should depends from the average number of points that has to be checked if inside the range (but I am not sure how to estimate it, even for a single point a range search inside a circle still has to be done). In the worst case of a large R we have to check all points and complexity deteriorates to O(N).

Thanks.

Comment: This is a great question and while I don't immediately have an answer, perhaps results that apply to k-d trees and other multidimensional search trees might apply here? Our theoretical understanding of those structures is still not that great, but with some (fairly unrealistic) assumptions about the distribution of points we can prove k-d trees solve nearest-neighbor searching in time O(log n) expected.

Comment: Thanks. What confuses me is that k-d must have worst complexity for 2D than quadtree. The O(log n) is actually log2(N) for k-d and log4(N) for qtree. k-d will have bigger average height than qtree, hence more checks? But for both this is not the complexity of the complete search but rather for finding a starting point (parent) where a range search must continue (even for a single nearest point). Thus the real complexity must include a second linear term O(k). Wikipedia and theory is very vague how to estimate the complexity of the whole search.

Comment: You're correct that a runtime complexity of O(log n) might hide different constant factors. While a quadtree does partition space into four regions, you have to do two comparisons at each level to determine which region to descend into (versus one for a k-d tree), so I'd expect that terms that depend purely on the branching factor of the tree would actually be offset by the work done per level. For a range search, I agree that there has to be some O(k) term, where k is the number of elements returned, though for a single nearest-neighbor search that isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: templatetypedef -  for trees with dim>1 there is always O(k) term, even for a single nearest neighbor. It is different than BST where it is trivial to find the nearest neighbor from the path to the lowest parent, you keep a min distance during the descend, one of the parents is always the nearest neighbor, so for BST search complexity is O(log n)  (if we don't take in account the additional price of keeping track of min_diff?). But for qtree and k-d this will not work, you need to go up in the tree and to check parents and some of the other children. With k-d three there are more checks....

Comment: You don’t necessarily have to have an O(k) term even if you have to back up in the tree during the search. As an example, suppose you only have to back up at layer log log n or lower. Then the total number of extra nodes visited would be 2^(log log n) = log n, so the overall cost is still asymptotically O(log n), just with a larger constant factor.